# Two nonisomorphic tensor products - where is the error?

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products, fake-proofs, galois-connections

Where is the error in the following?

In the category of all posets with increasing maps:

With product order it becomes a monoidal category.

With "product" which maps a pair posets into the set of Galois connections between them it also becomes a monoidal category.

So there are two ways to define the tensor product. Thus product order between two posets is isomorphic to the set of Galois connections between two posets.

Comment: There are categories which are monoidal in many ways, with different, non-isomorphic tensor functors.

Comment: Consider the category which has exactly four objects and no non-identity morphisms. Find all monoidal structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mariano Suárez pointed out in the comments above you can have many non equivalent monoidal structures over a category.

As an example consider $\mathbf{Set}$: both the cartesian product and the coproduct induce a monoidal structure over $\mathbf{Set}$, nonetheless they are far from being the same thing. If you take the set $[3]$, whose element are the numbers $0$, $1$ and $2$, you have that $[3]\amalg[3]$ has cardinality $6$ while $[3]\times[3]$ has cardinality $9$, hence they cannot be isomorphic. So the two monoidal structures cannot be equivalent since their tensor products fail to give even isomorphic objects for the same arguments.